# Como emitir os dados de sub-components com Vuejs 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Como posso obter todos os itens marcados a partir de um component em outra instancia tendo a seguinte estrutura em árvore?

```js
window.Event = new Vue();

Vue.component('tree', {
 props: {
   model: {
     type: Array,
      default: function () { return [] }
    },
    
    checkeds: {
     type: Array,
      default: function () { return [] }
    }
  },
  methods: {
   changeCheck: function() {
     Event.$emit('treeChangeCheck', this.check);
    }
  },
  data: function(){
   return {
     check: this.checkeds
    };
  },
 template: '\
     <ul v-if="model.length > 0">\
       <li><b>Checkeds:</b> {{ check }}</li>\
      <li v-for="item in model">\
         <input type="checkbox" @change="changeCheck" v-model="check" :value="item.id">\
          {{ item.name }}\
         <tree :model="item.children" :checkeds="checkeds"></tree>\
        </li>\
    </ul>\
  '
});

new Vue({
 el: '#demo',
  created: function(){
   Event.$on('treeChangeCheck', this.updateValue);
  },
  methods: {
   updateValue: function(value){
     this.$set(this, 'inputCheckeds', value);
    }
  },
  data: function() {
   return {
     inputCheckeds: [],
     list: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Parent a',        
            children: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Children a.a'
                },

                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Children a.b'
                }
            ]        
          },
          
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Parent b',        
            children: [
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'Children b.a'
                },

                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: 'Children b.b'
                }
            ]        
          }
       ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul, li{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p{
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>
  inputCheckeds: 
  {{ inputCheckeds }}
  </p>

  <tree :model="list" :checkeds="[1, 4, 2, 3]" @treeChangeInput="updateValue"></tree>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução alternativa utilizando localStorage para armazenar e controlar os campos marcados/desmarcados e com isso sempre emitir apenas os itens marcados para outra instância vue.

Segue código: https://jsfiddle.net/7vp4yd46/